# Variants hover not applying in TailwindCss

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a custom class set-up, I'm trying to add variants but seems the behaviour doesn't change from classic CSS.

```css
@layer components {
    @variants hover, focus {
        .btn-primary {
            background-color:blue;
            
        }
    }

    .btn-primary{
        @apply bg-primary rounded-sm border-4 border-primary rounded-sm text-white text-base py-2 px-4 capitalize transition-all;
        
    }
}
```

If the variants is after the `.btn-primary`, then it applies the blue background like it's nothing.
Hover nor focus work.

Here what I've add in my tailwind config based on other posts I've seen :

```js
variants: {
    extend: {
        backgroundColor: ['hover'],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `hover:` and `focus:` prefixes directly in your `.btn-primary` definition.

```css
.btn-primary {
    @apply bg-primary hover:bg-blue-700 focus:bg-blue-700 rounded-sm border-4 text-white text-base py-2 px-4 capitalize transition-all;  
}
```

You also don't need to add the `hover` and `focus` variants to the `backgroundColor` property in the config as it's already enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't understand why they would recommand using variants in the docs, which doesn't work

Comment: The way you were configuring the variants would mean that you'd be using the class as `hover:btn-primary` or `focus:btn-primary`. This has its uses, but wasn't exactly what you required.

Comment: Ok I see, what if I want to use classes like classic CSS, because btn-primary:hover { } does not work since it's overrided by Tailwind ? Is it possible ?

Comment: You can create utilities with regular CSS for cases where TailwindCSS utilities aren't enough, see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities#using-css.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !